# If dot product is commutative, why does MATLAB give different answers?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Why does the dot() function in MATLAB return different expressions based on the order in which I pass vectors?

[image]

Comment: The premise of your question is incorrect.  The "dot product" of complex vectors is not commutative.

Comment: Which component could be a complex number?

Comment: I guess the confusion arises because `f` is symbolic (`x` and `y` could be complex) whereas `u` is explicitly real-valued.

Comment: Thank you that clears it up.  So any vector containing a variable (not limited to reals) is complex.

Comment: I don't have matlab, but according to this link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-for-symbolic-objects.html
you can add assumptions to symbolic variables. `x = sym('x', 'real');y = sym('y', 'real');` That may clear things up.

Comment: You can declare that x and y are real using "syms x y real".

Comment: Note that the dot product of two complex vectors $a$ and $b$ can be defined either as $a^{H}b$ or as $ab^{H}$.  Different authors use different definitions, and confusion between the two can sometimes cause problems, although both definitions are antisymmetric.

Comment: @BrianBorchers $ab^H$ dimensionally is a matrix, if $a$ and $b$ are column vectors as in the usual convention. I think you meant $a^H b$ and $b^H a$.

Comment: Sorry for the shorthand.  The point is that depending on your convention you take either the conjugate of the first vector or the second vector in the product.  The point remains that this can cause confusion...

Comment: @ChennaK great trick!  I'll definitely be using that.